# generics / interface method not applicable

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface Vegetable with, for example, Apples, Carrots...
I then have a class Collector of generic type, they can be Collector of cauliflower, carrots etc...
I need to implement a function to give the carriedObject of one Collector to another, the problem is that if I have I try  Collector.giveTo(Collector) it doesn't recognize that Apples are extended from Vegetable.
I tried doing this with an instanceof, with no success

Here is the constructor of my class Collector :

```
/** define collectors able to collect (and carry) one specific type T of objects
 * only one T object can be carried at a time
 */

public class Collector<T> {

private String name;
protected  T carriedObject = null;

/**
 * Creates a Collector object with a name and no carriedObject (carriedObject = null)
 * @param name a String, the name of the Collector
 */
public Collector(String name) {
this.name = name;
this.carriedObject = carriedObject;
}
```

and the code for some methods used :

```
/** 
 * give the carriedObject to another Collector
 * @param other the Collector to give the carriedObject to
 * @throws AlreadyCarryingException if the other Collector is already carrying an object
 */
public void giveTo(Collector<T> other) throws AlreadyCarryingException {
    if (this instanceof Vegetable && other instanceof Vegetable){
        if (other.getCarriedObject() != null){
            throw new AlreadyCarryingException("Le collector porte deja un objet");
        }
        else {
            other.take(this.drop());
        }
    }

/**
 * drops the carriedObject setting it to null
 */
public T drop(){
    T tmp = this.carriedObject;
    this.carriedObject = null;
    return tmp;
}

/**
 * allows the Collector to take an object and sets it as his carriedObject
 * @param object the Object to take
 * @throws AlreadyCarryingException if the Collector is already carrying an object
 */
public void take(T object) throws AlreadyCarryingException {
    //Collector is already carrying an object
    if (this.carriedObject != null) {
        throw new AlreadyCarryingException("Le collector porte deja un objet");
    }
    else{
        this.carriedObject = object;
    }
}
```

An example :
I added the code of take and drop

and an example :

```
Collector<Carrot> carrotCollector1 = new Collector<Carrot>("carrot-collector-1");
Collector<Vegetable> vegetableCollector = new Collector<Vegetable>("vegetable-collector");
carrotCollector1.giveTo(vegetableCollector);
```

and that's the error I get :

> The method giveTo(Collector) in the type Collector is
>   not applicable for the arguments (Collector)

Comment: In your call `carrotCollector1.giveTo(vegetableCollector)` you're passing a parameter of type `Collector<Vegetable>` while it expects type `Collector<Carrot>`. The solution provided by @Joakim should do.

Comment: @RobertKock [not really](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52498707/1059372)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way would be to change your method to:

```
public void giveTo(Collector<? super T> other) throws AlreadyCarryingException {
   // ... omitted some code  
   other.take(drop());
}
```

Comment: @Rémy.W np, but before you say `thx`, it might be important to understand why it works. I'll leave this for you to read, look at `PECS` and covariance and contravariance...